# Convert spark dataframe having list<Values> to rows using sparklyR

Tags: r, sparkr, sparklyr

I have a spark data frame that has list(values) in each row. I want to flatten the data by converting list of values to rows using **sparklyr**. Here is the sample data.

```
  id   colA     colB  colC
1: 1 list<> 4b,8b,2b list<>
2: 2 list<> 7b,2b,2b list<>
```

My output should look like this:

```
   id colA colB  colC
1:  1    1   4b FALSE
2:  1    2   8b FALSE
3:  1    3   2b FALSE
4:  2    1   7b FALSE
5:  2    2   2b FALSE
6:  2    3   2b FALSE
```

My data is of medium size(around 200M records). **So I don't want to collect the data into R memory to perform this operation**.

Here is the reproducible dataset

```
data.table(structure(list(id = list(1,2), 
               colA = list(list(1, 2, 3),list(1, 2, 3)), 
               colB = list(as.raw(c(0x4b, 0x8b, 0x2b)),as.raw(c(0x7b, 0x2b, 0x2b))), 
               colC = list(list(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),list(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))
              ),
          .Names = c("id", "colA", "colB", "colC"), 
          row.names = c(NA, -1L),
          class = c("data.frame","data.table")))
```

Comment: Do you need `dt1[, lapply(.SD, unlist)]`. The 'id' 2 rows showed in the expected output is not in the input structure which shhowed only a single row

Comment: I just fixed it. I had a hard time creating sample data. Thanks for the solution in data.table way, My data is quite huge, so I'm looking for some solution using spark API's.